# Certificate pinning in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, pinning

I am creating an iPad app that accesses HTTPS web services. I want to implement pinning, but am having issues.

This class creates the Alamofire Manager (mostly taken from documentation):

```
class NetworkManager {

    var manager: Manager?

    init() {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "www.google.co.uk": .PinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            ),
            "insecure.expired-apis.com": .DisableEvaluation
        ]

        manager = Alamofire.Manager(
            configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }
}
```

This function makes the call:

```
static let networkManager = NetworkManager()

public static func testPinning() {
    networkManager.manager!.request(.GET, "https://www.google.co.uk").response { response in
        if response.1 != nil {
            print("Success")
            print(response.1)
            print(response.1?.statusCode)
        } else {
            print("Error")
            print(response.3)
        }
    }
}
```

The [certificate is saved](https://superuser.com/a/97203/156776) in the project and shows under 'Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources'.

I am currently receiving the following error every time I make the request (from the else block in `testPinning()`):

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.google.co.uk/, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.google.co.uk/})
```

Comment: What certificate did you include? Have you have checked what `ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle()` returns (i.e. if it actually includes the certificate)? Wouldn't be too surprised if Google used multiple certificates for the same domain.

Comment: `ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle()` returns 0, which I don't understand. Is there a specific way in which I should add the .cer certificates into the bundle? Regarding Google, that is an example site to replace the one I am developing, but the above problem is the same.

Comment: You mean it returns an empty array? The return value of that call should be an array, not a number. You may want to try `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType(".cer", inDirectory: nil)` to see if the file is found in the bundle (if it is, it would then probably point to an issue with the certificate file contents). Anything showing up in the logs when `ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle()` is called?

Comment: Yes that is correct, I meant an array of 0 values. On closer inspection, that line of code can be found inside [link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift#L128)`certificatesInBundle()`. In the for loop there, the certificate is found, but line 138 is preventing the certificate from being added to the array. I suspect it might also be the contents of the .cer, although it opens fine in Xcode (any suggestions on how I should save the certificate, instead of the method linked in the question?). Also, how could I check those logs?

Comment: When you export a certificate in Firefox, you have a "format" pop-up at the bottom of the file browser. What format did you pick? I believe you need "X.509 Certificate (DER)" (per the documentation of [`SecCertificateCreateWithData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/#//apple_ref/c/func/SecCertificateCreateWithData) which states "Returns NULL if the data passed in the `data` parameter is not a valid **DER-encoded X.509 certificate**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: Using the .der format certificate seems to have solved the problem, the success code is now reached when making the request. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem ... any thing help me . could you please tell me the solution to yours ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, the issue was that the certificate was saved in the wrong format.

`ServerTrustPolicy.certificatesInBundle()` finds all certificates in the bundle based on a list of extensions, then tries to load them using `SecCertificateCreateWithData`. Per its documentation, this function:

> Returns NULL if the data passed in the data parameter is not a valid
>   DER-encoded X.509 certificate

When you export a certificate in Firefox, you have a "format" pop-up at the bottom of the file browser. Select "X.509 Certificate (DER)", and you should get a certificate in the right format for this purpose.

Answer (score 10):

First, you need to download the certificate. The best way is to download the certificate on the Firefox browser.

**Step 1**

Go to your webpage/ API and click the lock icon to get a certificate.

[image]

**Step 2**

Click View Certificate

[image]

**Step 3**

Click Certificate Fields tab's first section and click export

[image]

**Step 4**

Select the Format:- DER

[image]

**Step 5**

Drag and drop the file into your XCode Project

[image]

**Step 6**

Add Certificate under 'Targets > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources'

[image]

**Step 7**

Add Network Manager File. Replace your URL with google.com

```
 import Foundation
 import Alamofire
 import SwiftyJSON

 class MYPNetworkManager {


     var Manager: SessionManager?

     init() {
         let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
             "https://google.com": .pinCertificates(
                 certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                 validateCertificateChain: true,
                 validateHost: true
             ),
             "insecure.expired-apis.com": .disableEvaluation
         ]

         Manager = SessionManager(
             serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: 
 serverTrustPolicies)
         )

     }
 }
```

**Step 8**

Add a file to get the session manager

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class APIPinning {

    private static let NetworkManager = MYPNetworkManager()

    public static func getManager() -> SessionManager {
        return NetworkManager.Manager!
    }
 }
```

**Step 9**

Use this session manager on Alamofire
eg:-

```
 public static func testPinning() {
NetworkManager.Manager!.request("YourURL", method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: MConnect.headersWithToken)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON { response in

        print(response)
        switch response.result {
        case .success:

            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json)
            } else {

            }

        case .failure:
            print("Error")
        }
}
}
```

Comment: your code is not working in Alamofire 5. Can you please update your code to Alamofire 5 or can you share a link to get alamofire 5 code please?

Answer (score 1):

After Alamofire version +5 there was a big change I'll list here what I did to do a certificate pinning. I was targeting Moya and since Moya as a layer above Alamofire what works for Alamofire should work with Moya.

First To get a server certificate you need to open it in the browser then click on the lock icon
Then you need to click on the certificate as the screenshot shows.
[image]
after that you need to drag this certificate to your desktop or wherever download it look at the screenshot below.
[image]
Then you need to add it to your project using add file to in Xcode check screenshoot.
[image]
Here is my code For Alamofire:

```
var session: Session!

class ViewController: UIViewController {

func testPinning() {


let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "stackoverflow.com": PublicKeysTrustEvaluator()
]

let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)

session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)


session
    .request("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611112/certificate-pinning-in-alamofire/55902588#55902588", method: .get)
    .validate()
    .response(completionHandler: { [weak self] response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print(response.data)
        case .failure(let error):
            switch error {
            case .serverTrustEvaluationFailed(let reason):
                // The reason here is a place where you might fine-tune your
                // error handling and possibly deduce if it's an actualy MITM
                // or just another error, like certificate issue.
                //
                // In this case, this will show `noRequiredEvaluator` if you try
                // testing against a domain not in the evaluators list which is
                // the closest I'm willing to setting up a MITM. In production,
                // it will most likely be one of the other evaluation errors.
                print(reason)
            default:
                print("default")
            }
        }
    })

}
```

For Moya you will need to add that session to your moya provider.

```
let evaluators: [String: ServerTrustEvaluating] = [
    "stackoverflow.com": PublicKeysTrustEvaluator()
]

let manager = ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)

session = Session(serverTrustManager: manager)


let provider = MoyaProvider<YourStackOVerflowProvider>(
    session: session
)


provider.request(.pluginManger) { response in
    switch response {
    case .failure(let err):
        print(err)
    case .success(let response):
        print(response)
    }
}
```