# Alamofire, Use of undeclared types

Tags: swift, xcode, ssl, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to SSL Pinning.
For this, I use the below code:

```swift
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON   

class CertificateManager {
    init() {
        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "test.example.com": .pinCertificates(
                certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
                validateCertificateChain: true,
                validateHost: true
            ),
            "insecure.expired-apis.com": .disableEvaluation
        ]

        let sessionManager = SessionManager(
            serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )
    }
}
```

but these errors occurred:

[image: Use of undeclared type error]

My pod file is: `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.2'`.

I searched and tested some solutions, but can't resolve errors. How can I fix this?

I tried this answer too. [+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902588/1240052)

Comment: Did you do `import Alamofire`?

Comment: Yes I did, I import these `import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON`

Comment: Clean and rebuild project, did you try that?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, I tried this. Clean, Build, Also wipe DeivenData.

Comment: Alamofire v5 has new APIs but they haven't created a migration guide yet because it's still a release candidate. You can read more about it in [this ticket](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2755). See also [Kamran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2395636/kamran)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58363900/5928180) below

Answer (score 5):

In `Alamofire` version you are using, `ServerTrustPolicy` and `SessionManager` no longer exist. You can try the newly introduced api's as below,

```
let pinEvaluator = PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: Bundle.main.af.certificates,
                                                    acceptSelfSignedCertificates: true,
                                                    performDefaultValidation: true,
                                                    validateHost: true)
let disableEvaluator = DisabledEvaluator()

let trustManager = ServerTrustManager.init(evaluators:
    ["test.example.com": pinEvaluator,
     "insecure.expired-apis.com": disableEvaluator
    ])

let sessionManager = Session.init(configuration: .default, serverTrustManager: trustManager)
```

Comment: What is the use of pinEvaluator and disableEvaluator?

Comment: @AiraSamson To encrypt your data for secure transmission you use certificate pinning(`pinEvaluator`). If some host is disabled for evaluation then you would use `DisabledEvaluator`

Answer (score 4):

As @Kamran post.

`Alamofire 5.0`, all api has [big change](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%205.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#breaking-api-changes)