# Execute CURL command with private key in Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, alamofire

Execute it in Alamofire on Swift language

**curl -k --cert client.crt --key clientprivate.key -X GET 'https://example.com:8443/test**

I assume that I need to configure in this place

```
session = Session(
            serverTrustManager: ServerTrustManager(evaluators: evaluators)
          )
```

It is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Certificate pinning in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611112/certificate-pinning-in-alamofire)

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/ssl-pinning-with-alamofire-5-538ad7b8ee0f

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.